# modifying algorithm to generate unique permutations in a string that contains duplicates

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation, dynamic-programming

I'm aware of handling the issue with duplicates if I were to use a swap and permute method for generating permutations as shown [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/).

However, I'm using a different approach where I **place current character between any two characters, at the beginning and at the end**, of all of the permutations generated without the current character.

How can I modify my code below to give me only unique permutations in a string that contains duplicates

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Permutations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "baab";
        System.out.println(fun(str, 0));
        System.out.println("number of Permutations =="+fun(str, 0).size());
    }

    static ArrayList<String> fun(String str, int index)
    {
        if(index == str.length())
        {
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add("");
            return al;
        }

        /* get return from lower frame */
        ArrayList<String> rec = fun(str, index+1);

        /* get character here */
        char c = str.charAt(index);

        /* to each of the returned Strings in ArrayList, add str.charAt(j) */
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<rec.size();i++)
        {
            String here = rec.get(i);
            ret.add(c + here);
            for(int j = 0;j<here.length();j++)
                ret.add(here.substring(0,j+1) + c + here.substring(j+1,here.length()));
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

At the moment, a string such as "bab" generates the following output, which contain abb and bba multiple times.

```
[bab, abb, abb, bba, bba, bab]
number of Permutations ==6
```

PS : I do not want to use a hashmap/Set to keep track of my duplicates and see whether they were encountered previously.

Comment: Is this not the question from Codechef?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj, hi. As I said, I'm aware of a solution to solve the problem as such, I'm looking for a modification for this particular implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're iterating through the string and adding the character at each position, if you find a character in the string that is the same as the one you are inserting, break after inserting the new character immediately before it. This means that strings with the same character more than once can only be formed one way (by inserting in reverse order) so duplicates can't happen.

```
for(int j = 0;j<here.length();j++)
{
    if(here.charAt(j) == c)
        break;  
    ret.add(here.substring(0,j+1) + c + here.substring(j+1,here.length()));
}
```

A general approach to solving these problems involving generating sets without duplicates is to think of a property that only one of each set of duplicates will have, and then enforce that as a constraint. For example in this case the constraint is "all duplicated characters are added in reverse order" (forward order would work just as well, but you'd have to flip the loop direction). For a combination problem where the order isn't important, the constraint could be "items in each list are in ascending order". And so on.

Comment: this is so elegant. Abs awesome!

Comment: just had a question. Say, our string is babcd. Say, I have generated all 24 permutations with abcd and am now, at the step where I'm going to insert b at each of the locations. According to your logic, for a string like abcd, upon adding 'b' we generate 1)babcd and 2)abbcd, but break after that. My question is, it makes sense to ignore a permutation like ab + 'b' + cd  == abbcd again. But how can we ignore the combinations ahead such as abc + b + d == abcbd. I drew the recursion and see that these are generated in some other frame. But how is it that all of these are taken care of ?

Comment: That would be taken care of by generating acbd and then inserting b in the second position, which doesn't break the rule.

Comment: yes, yes. I did check for all of them by drawing the recursion tree, and verify that we're indeed not missing any out. But my question is, how does this work that none of these combinations are left out, and how we can BREAK. How are all the remaining permutations in aabcdefghijk taken care of, if we BREAK at the very first character in abcdefghijk ?

Comment: You're only breaking out of the inner loop, that's why. The outer loop will continue generating permutations.

Comment: all that's true, and the algorithm works as well. But I don't understand the logic behind just quitting when you encounter the character to be same as the one you're processing. What about the rest of the characters, and inserting current character between those spots? I understand it's taken care of in some other iteration of outer for loop. But my question is, what is the scientific explanation for not missing out any permutation in spite of just quitting? Are we just getting lucky since there's so many permutations, and we'll cover all, or is there another reason?

Comment: Basically we've changed the spec from "generate all permutations" to "generate all permutations where any duplicate characters are added in reverse order", and exhaustively listing them. If we break, the only permutations we will miss out on are the ones that violate the constraint. It seems like "magic" and it's tempting to say "hold on, what about X?" because usually we think of algorithms in a top down way. But this is based on reasoning from the bottom up about individual examples. Once you've proved it at the case level, reality has to warp itself around that to avoid a contradiction.

Comment: what do you mean by "reverse order"?

Comment: It means that a character can only be added to a string before existing instances of that character in the string. E.g. adding b to abcd to make babcd is ok. Adding b to abcd to make abcbd is not ok.

Comment: Another way to look at it: suppose you permute the string abb and get two duplicates of bab. One would have been formed by adding b to the start of ab. One would have been formed by adding b to the end of ba. Disallowing the second removes the duplicate.